# Twilio client inside chrome extension. User denied access to microphone when device.connect runs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-taskrouter

Hi I am developing chrome extension using Twilio Client JS library and Task Router JS SDK. I successfully registered Twilio device and receive on ready event also on background script. I also setup task router worker and receive events too. When I place a call reservation.accepted event fired. When I run device.connect() function I receive following error. Below are the logs of events received. I also gave microphone permission to the site in which this extension is running. I am using inject page strategy and load extension content inside iframe and append to body. I am also receiving this warning in my background script console.
**Warning: Unable to set audio output devices. Error: Devices not found: default**

Need help

```
device.on('error', (error) => {
       console.log("Device on error:", error);
    });
```

[image]